ERROR 2003 (HY000): Can't connect to MySQL server on 'dbexample.something.ap-south-1.rds.amazonaws.com:3306
I have created ubuntu 22.04 server in azure and allowed 3306 in outbound of NSG attached to azure server. Have also opened the inbound port as 3306 in security group of AWS MySql RDS instance for 0.0.0.0/0 as well as for public ip of azure server. While connecting with command mysql -h dbexample.something.ap-south-1.rds.amazonaws.com -P 3306 -u admin -p
then I am getting below error ERROR 2003 (HY000): Can't connect to MySQL server on 'dbexample.something.ap-south-1.rds.amazonaws.com:3306. Please help to fix it.

This is not a programming or sw development related question. You need to configure your network, database, and security settings correctly to enable remote access.

Please check a few things in AWS:

Please check if RDS Publicly Accessible property to Yes. AWS Link
Please check if RDS subnet has Route Table/NACL in place to allow connection from public network.
[Debug 1] You can create a test EC2 to check RDS connection
[Debug 2] You can create a connection from local PC using SQL application tool to check remote connection to RDS. AWS Link

